# Change of rep requirements after beta: should post-beta rep be listed on the privilege page(s)?

Tags: feature-request, privileges, graduating-sites

I think it would be nice to see if you actually will retain a privilege (at current rep) after beta.

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before - but I can't find the original

Comment: @ChrisF here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/can-we-grandfather-in-rep-abilities-as-sites-leave-beta

Comment: So, it hasn't been asked before.  I'm not asking to retain privs, I'm asking for showing *if* one would/will retain privs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary. Just go look at the requirements on a graduated site, and see where your rep stands.

Comment: It might be worth adding a note to avoid SO/SU/SF because as per [Reputation requirements compared](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) they're a little different.