# Privileges Lost: Really?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we grandfather in rep abilities as sites leave beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/can-we-grandfather-in-rep-abilities-as-sites-leave-beta)

I participated in the beta for the apple.stackexchange.com site, which launched today.

I understand that launched sites require more rep for a given privilege, but it feels pretty unfair that I've now lost a bunch of my capabilities.

I think it would be much friendlier to let beta users grandfather in to these privileges because, really, losing stuff sucks. Even more when you've worked hard for it and supported a developing site.

Anyone agree?