# Allow private beta users to maintain gained privileges

Tags: feature-request, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we grandfather in rep abilities as sites leave beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/can-we-grandfather-in-rep-abilities-as-sites-leave-beta)

I would like to suggest the benefits gained by users in a private beta should be maintained once a site goes into public beta or live.

I was able to edit questions during private beta and this has now changed since the site went public beta today. I know I will get this privilege back very soon, but I don't understand the logic of taking it away?

I was trusted to edit questions during the private beta, why not in the public beta?

I understand why the mark moves, but shouldn't only move for users who come on board after the private beta.

I could create gallery chat rooms, all of a sudden I'm not allowed to because the site went public. I would assume that private beta users who had already attained enough rep would be more trustworthy.